# "Resource not found " when page is deployed using a feature

Tags: 2010, feature, publishing-page

I am running through deployment problem.

I have a feature with pages and required dlls. When I deploy the solution it gets successfully deployed.

- I can see feature (active) in my site.
- I can see solution (deployed) in my central admin.
- I can see that dlls and pages in 14 hive and in my website folder.
- I can see modified web.config file.

But when I try to access the page it throws

> Resource can not be found "
>   Requested URL: `/_layouts/xyz/Pages/Home.aspx`.

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Don't You have any linked ASCX or other resources in "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES"?

Comment: Is the page published?

Comment: @GennadyG: Ya i am having that resources too.

Comment: Possible some linked files are not included in project. Hard to say more without a project.